# Is there any way to use MiniProfiler within a Rails-API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc-mini-profiler, rails-api

I'm trying to find a way to use **MiniProfiler for Ruby** in a **Rails-API** app ?

Thanks,

Santiago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out that **first browsing the action I wanna profile** and **then a HTML page from the public folder** like 404.html, will show me the stack of all the profiling done since last check.

Santiago

Comment: indeed. That makes the job. 404.html will contain the profile stacks for each API call you made beforehand. It can also be a useful workaround when working with any other kind of responses, such as XML, etc.